# php keep only the first 4 lines of a text file when uploading

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload, trim

I'm using the following code to upload a txt file to my server..

```
<form style="margin-bottom:2px;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formUploadFile">     
            <label>Select txt file to upload:</label>
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="Submit"/>
            <br>
        </form> 

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
            {
                $errors = array();
                $uploadedFiles = array();
                $extension = array("txt");
                $bytes = 1024;
                $KB = 1024;
                $totalBytes = $bytes * $KB;
                $UploadFolder = "tmp_txt_store";

                $counter = 0;

                foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name){
                    $temp = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
                    $name = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];

                    if(empty($temp))
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    $counter++;
                    $UploadOk = true;

                    if($_FILES["files"]["size"][$key] > $totalBytes)
                    {
                        $UploadOk = false;
                        array_push($errors, $name." file size is larger than the 1 MB.");
                    }

                    $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if(in_array($ext, $extension) == false){
                        $UploadOk = false;
                        array_push($errors, $name." invalid file type.");
                    }

                    if(file_exists($UploadFolder."/".$name) == true){
                        $UploadOk = false;
                        array_push($errors, $name." file already exists.");
                    }

                    if($UploadOk == true){
                        $name = "my.txt";
                        move_uploaded_file($temp,$UploadFolder."/".$name);
                        array_push($uploadedFiles, $name);
                    }

                }

                if($counter>0){
                    if(count($errors)>0)
                    {
                        echo "<b>Errors:</b>";
                        foreach($errors as $error)
                        {
                            echo " ".$error.",";
                        }
                        echo "<br/>";
                    }

                    if(count($uploadedFiles)>0){
                        echo "<b>Uploaded:</b>";
                        echo "=";
                        foreach($uploadedFiles as $fileName)
                        {
                            echo " ".$fileName.",";
                        }
                        echo "<br/>";

                        echo "DONE!";
                                            }                                           
                }
                else{
                    echo "ERROR: Please press the browse button and select a txt file to upload.";
                }

            }
        ?>
```

And I would like to keep only the first 4 lines of text, so trim off (delete) all lines of text (after the 4th line) before it gets uploaded.

So

```
line 1 text
line 2 text
line 3 text
line 4 text
line 5 text
line 6 text
line 7 text
<!--And so on-->
```

Becomes

```
line 1 text
line 2 text
line 3 text
line 4 text
```

How do I go about doing this? 
I have tried a few suggstions looking at answers to other (similar) questions but being a so novice at php I'm really not getting anywhere with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just read the first four line, then overwrite the file.

```
    $fp = fopen($file_path);
    $num = 4;
    while($num-- > 0 && $line = fgets($fp)){
        $lines [] = $line;
    }
    fclose($file_path);
    file_put_contents($file_path,join("",$lines));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer, but I have no idea where in my code to correctly put this for it to work. Could you edit your answer and show me the code in place within my code please?

Comment: Can anyone please help me and let me know where in my code I put this example code as I am struggling with this one.